# Removing Image Button Padding (Android)

Tags: android, image, button, padding

I have Buttons that look like the top image for the landscape orientation:

[image: screenshot]

I want it to look like the bottom image.

Here's my .xml code for these buttons.

```
<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow7"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:weightSum="1.0" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/appHome"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".5"
        android:background="@null"
        android:contentDescription="Home"
        android:cropToPadding="true"
        android:scaleType="fitEnd"
        android:src="@drawable/home_bar" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/menuHome"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:background="@null"
        android:contentDescription="Menu"
        android:cropToPadding="true"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:src="@drawable/menu_bar" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/back"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".5"
        android:background="@null"
        android:contentDescription="Back"
        android:cropToPadding="true"
        android:scaleType="fitStart"
        android:src="@drawable/back_bar" />

</TableRow>
```

Comment: check this ansewr https://stackoverflow.com/a/67302375/4797289

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up fixing this by switching my TableLayout to a LinearLayout. Here's my code unless anyone else comes across this problem:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/appHome"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@null"
        android:contentDescription="Home"
        android:scaleType="fitEnd"
        android:src="@drawable/home_bar_grey" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/menuHome"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@null"
        android:contentDescription="Menu"
        android:onClick="menuhome"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/menu_bar" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/back"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@null"
        android:contentDescription="Back"
        android:scaleType="fitStart"
        android:src="@drawable/exit_bar" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: the problem with setting background to null is that you lose the gray tint that comes with an ImageButton on click.

Answer (score 8):

You cannot do that with the default buttons, the buttons 9 patches have a padding in them (both, holo and the pre holo buttons). 
You can see that [here](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/drawable-hdpi/btn_default_focused_holo.9.png?raw=true).

If you want buttons without padding then you'll have to modify the 9 patches and create your own theme:

```
<style name="myTheme" parent="....">
    <item name="imageButtonStyle">@style/myImageButton</item>
</style>
```

and your imageButtonStyle:

```
<style name="myImageButton" parent="Widget.ImageButton">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/myCostomizedNinePatchSelectorWithoutPadding</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

An easier alternative to creating your own 9 patch image to remove the margin is to set the background to null.

For example, add the following to res/styles.xml:

```
<style name="MarginlessImageButton" parent="android:Widget.ImageButton">
    <item name="android:background">@null</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="android:imageButtonStyle">@style/MarginlessImageButton</item>
</style>
```

You should now find that all ImageButtons have zero margin, regardless of whether defined in XML or created programatically.

Answer (score 1):

Use `scaleType` property , you can see icon with same size of `ImageButton`

Answer (score 0):

Use negative padding on the `ImageButton` in your xml to shrink the padding used.

```
android:paddingLeft="-5dip"
android:paddingRight="-5dip"
```

Note the above is just an example... you'll need to mess with the numbers to adjust for your specific case to make things look correct.

Comment: No matter how high the numbers, I still am getting the same weird padding.

Comment: It might be margin instead of padding... same trick applies, use negative numbers.

Comment: I just tried margin with the same result... I tried both for the hell of it too. There's still all the invisible space.

Answer (score 0):

//remove the `android:weightSum` use width as `match_parent`

//give `android:layout_weight="1"` for all imageButton

//use `android:scaleType="fitXY"` for all

```
<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow7"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/appHome"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@null"
        android:contentDescription="Home"
        android:cropToPadding="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/home_bar" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/menuHome"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:background="@null"
        android:contentDescription="Menu"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:cropToPadding="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/menu_bar" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/back"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@null"
        android:contentDescription="Back"
        android:cropToPadding="true"
       android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/back_bar" />

</TableRow>
```

Comment: This works, but it stretches out the images, which is what I don't want.

Comment: Then remove the android:scaleType="fitXY".

Comment: When I did this, I achieved the same result as before (with the padding space thing)