# How to remove extra space in button when using drawable

Tags: android, button, drawable

I have a `Button` with no text and with a drawable on the right of it added through `setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds`. On the left, though, there is some unused space which I would like to remove. Is there a way to do that? The only way I have found to fix this in some way is setting the padding of the button in order to center the drawable.

Comment: I think Ahmad's answer can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14105631/removing-image-button-padding-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you won't use text, you should use ImageButton instead.

Just set setBackgroundDrawable and be happy ^^