# Xamarin Android: how to adjust Compass button position on the Map?

Tags: android, google-maps, xamarin.android, compass

I work on an app where the map is displayed through a `SupportMapFragment`.

We use a custom **"Find me" button** at the bottom right of the map. We have to display the **compass button** just at the top on the "Find me" button.

We display a List on the same screen, to display the corresponding POIs, as this works on Google Maps. When the user is sliding up the splitter between the list and the map, the "Find me" button is scrolling in the same time: so the margin between the "Find me" button and the splitter is always the same.

My problem is that the compass button is not moving with the "Find me" button, as it is managed through the code.

***Is there a way to move it dynamically, when the "Find me" button is moving?***

Comment: Would you post a demo so that we can test it for you?

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54029568/6950238) answer.