# How can I remove white spaces around an ImageButton?

Tags: android, padding, margin, imagebutton, android-imagebutton

How can I remove the white spaces around these ImageButtons?

[image: ImageButtons]

This is sample code for one one of the ImageButton:

```
<ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
        android:layout_width="64dp"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_circulo"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/imageButton2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14105631/removing-image-button-padding-android

Comment: Hi @GoltsevEugene, thanks for answering. I have read the link but I do not know how to "modify the 9 patches" of the default button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
android:background="@null" or 
android:background="#00000000"
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. However, that removes the gray background and I want to keep it. I can use `android:background="#00000000"` and use my gray color, but then it fills all the space. What I need is simply to remove the space around the gray square, keeping the meisures of the square and the gray color.

Comment: Try android:scaleType="fitXY" attribute in your ImageButton along with my answer. And that arrow like thing should be there ?